# How do I output content of specific file from zip achrive by `jar:` URL in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, url, jar, unzip

Given URL like `jar:file:///path/to/some/file.jar/path/inside/zip/hello.txt`, how do I uncompress and output specified file from specified archive automatically?

A script using `unzip` or `jar` or `7z` can obviously be written, but maybe there is already a tool somewhere that accepts URLs?

Comment: If you wanna edit the txt file instead of the class file, you can use Vim the `jar:file://.......`. If you want to rename the Txt file, you should uncompress the package. Don't know any better tool to do this.

Answer (score 0):

jar files are zip files, so you can do:

```
$ unzip -c file.jar file_to_extract
```

and the file will be uncompressed and shown.

Comment: The question is just elaborated, not changed. I already know how to extract a file from zip/jar. I just emphasized the point that URL handling (extracting zip filename and inner filename) is the main part of question, not extraction itself.